# Microsoft Windows port forwarding?

Tags: windows, networking

While there are no end of great tools for Linux/Unix, I seem to be having difficulty finding something which will run in MSWindows. I am aware of socat, however I need a port forwarder which can handle failover of the target service does not connect (I don't think this is possible using socat).

None of pound, balance or HAProxy seem to be available on MSWindows (if I'm wrong please tell me where I can get these).

Not averse to commercial softare, but I want a really simple and reliable tool.

Comment: Just see this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13285/Using-UPnP-for-Programmatic-Port-Forwardings-and-N

Comment: @WingedPanther: thanks but this does not seem to solve the problem of ensuring high availability and its primarily intended to solve the problem of remote port forwarding for a router to solve NAT problems. I'm trying to implement local port forwarding (with high availability). And running discovery within a datacentre is not the same as running it on an unsecured network.